# Unable to access BLOB using CDN in Azure

Tags: azure, cdn, azure-cdn

I have a storage account in azure,
It contains container as "images"
I am able to access my blob using following path
https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/images/image1.jpg

Now I have created CDN for https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net

& got some URL as follow for CDN

http://abcd55555.vo.msecnd.net/

But when I try to access my BLOB using CDN as follow

http://abcd55555.vo.msecnd.net/images/image1.jpg

I get 404 - Not Found Error.

I have EndPoint Enabled, HTTP Protocol Enabled,QUERY STRING STATUS Enabled.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Later I was able to access those BLOB's

I think that we need to wait for some time around 24 or 48 hours to be able to access those BLOBs.

EDIT: Later I come to know that, 60 minutes is delay that is 1 hour.

Comment: I'm now seeing it take between 15 - 60 minutes FYI

Comment: This seems like an error on Azure's part, it shouldn't 404. At least, based on the docs and what you'd expect from a good API. "Users who try to use the CDN domain name immediately may receive status code 400 (Bad Request) until the content is available via the CDN."

Comment: If the container name is not cdn then blob will not be cached?
Am I right?

Comment: Wow! why does it take so long (1 hour) to propagate CDN related changes)?

Answer (score 7):

Did you make your blob container public?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179354.aspx

and properly configured your CDN end point?

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-how-to-use/

Comment: Yes I have done both settings. That is why I was able to access my BLOB using BLOB URL (after making it public). I have created end point for CDN, from there itself I got URL of CDN. both URL's are mentioned in my question.

Comment: I would put this question to Azure, CDN is super easy to setup the only thing that is left to check is that you selected the right Blob account when you did the quick create

Comment: I also tried your Blob core address and received an error either the file isn't there or it isn't set to public. I also notice that you are using HTTPS if you want to use HTTPS you have to enable it at the endpoint

Comment: I'm having this same exact issue. Container is public and CDN end point is setup... yet it still shows 404 for everything that exists on the BLOB url. If someone figures this out, that would be awesome. Ridiculous that I'd have to pay $25 to get support from Microsoft when we're already in a subscription... smh

Comment: I think that we need to wait for some time around 24 or 48 hours to be .able to access those BLOBs

Comment: Yeah.. you are right.. There should be a 400 error code, not 404.. waiting time is also bigger than 1 hour, at least in my experience at the moment (waiting since 2 hours).. These delays really suck..

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this helped me a lot. My container access level was set to `Off` instead of `Public Blob` Didn't feel like setting it to `Public Container` because that seems like opendir (directory listing)